# multiple buttons posting to self through a javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, element

I am trying to set up a form to post to itself, but to also do some javascript in the middle of the process...  I have this working, but the next step is to be able to identify one of a number of buttons that were pressed that are on the form.

```
<button type="button" name="used" id="used" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getNewLocation(used)">Used Hole</button>
<button type="button" name="disused" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getNewLocation(used)">Disused Hole</button>
```

Example here are 2 of the buttons, but there are 4 of them.  getNewLocation then does the following to refresh the location before submitting back to the page.

```
function getNewLocation(x) {
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(sendPosition,showError,{enableHighAccuracy: true});
                    var elem = document.getElementById("button");
                    elem.value = x;

                } else { 
                    x = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
                }
            }

            function sendPosition(position) {
                document.getElementById("lat").value = position.coords.latitude;
                document.getElementById("long").value = position.coords.longitude;
                document.getElementById("acc").value = position.coords.accuracy;
                document.forms["point"].submit();
            }
```

This actually works but does not pull through the button value, but give the `$_POST` value of [button] as `object HTMLButtonElement` :-(

Can anyone point me in the right direction please??

Comment: Not sure, but `<input type="button">` instead of `button` might work ..? Usually this kind of data is delivered in hidden inputs, though.

Comment: What does it mean "the button value"? How do you set any value to the button? You use `getElementById("button")` - what's that?! Then you set some "value" to it and then think just a property of a button is sent over a form? Use input fields for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue you're encountering is trying to set the value of the button after accessing it with `var elem = document.getElementById("button");` You can notice that neither of your buttons have an `id` attribute of button so this won't work.

It might help that the button itself is passed to `getNewLocation` as the first argument, allowing you to set the `value` of it directly.

There are other issues with your code but in terms of right direction, I hope this helps.

```js
function getNewLocation(elem) {
  if (navigator.geolocation) { 
    // var elem = document.getElementById("button");
    elem.value = 'used';
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" name="used" id="used" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getNewLocation(this)">Used Hole</button>
<button type="button" name="disused" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getNewLocation(this)">Disused Hole</button>
```

Comment: He's passing some "used" property and set the value of the element (button) to this property. Or updates the property. Therefore your answer is just a suggestion about what is going on and not a definite one. Even though the part with the button is true and I've already wrote about it :)

Comment: I'm not sure the above makes sense...  I have 2 buttons and need to set an attribute element of the $_POST variable [button] to what the button is called so that I can then direct the code based on the $_POST["button"] variable.

Comment: So if one of the buttons sends getNewLocation(used), I would need to have $_POST["button"] = 'used'....  But if the other button is pressed onclick="getNewLocation(disused) would then refresh the position but $_POST["button"] would equal 'disused'

Comment: My bad....  I should have said that I have also tried to put a hidden input on the form, with the name and id of 'Button' and tried to set the value of that, using the script, before the submit, to no avail

Answer (score 0):

OK all, thanks for the great input...  It took a bit of time and more trying but I got there in the end....

```
<input type="hidden" name="button" id="button">
<button type="button" name="used" id="used" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getNewLocation('used')">Used Hole</button>
<button type="button" name="disused" id="disused" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getNewLocation('disused')">Disused Hole</button>
```

With this in the `<script>`

```
    function getNewLocation(x) {
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    var elem = document.getElementById("button");
                    elem.value = x;
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(sendPosition,showError,{enableHighAccuracy: true});

                } else { 
                    x = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
                }
            }

            function sendPosition(position) {
                document.getElementById("lat").value = position.coords.latitude;
                document.getElementById("long").value = position.coords.longitude;
                document.getElementById("acc").value = position.coords.accuracy;
                document.forms["point"].submit();
            }
```

Thanks again